# Phonegap getCurrentPosition not working on Android 2.x withouth wifi

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing an android app with phonegap 2.2 that tracks the user's position.

My problem is that in andoid 2.2 and 2.3, when the "use wireless networks" is off, the getCurrentPosition returns the following error:

```
{
    "message": "The last location provider was disabled",
    "code": 2
}
```

Even though the "Use GPS satellites" option is on.

I can see that foursquare and google maps under the same conditions, can get the phone's location.

I tried many settings with the options, here is two of my attempts:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    onSuccess,
    onError,
    {timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: Infinity}
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    onSuccess,
    onError,
    {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true}
};
```

I also have this permissions set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Both attempts gave me the same error response.

¿Anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show me the code you use calling the getCurrentPosition?

Comment: I assume you have tried enableHighAccuracy: true, I have this setting and everything works fine. Are you testing in the emulator? I sometimes have that error if I only send the position once, but if I send it twice it works (and on the device always works)

Comment: Yes I'm using enableHighAccuracy: true (edited my question). I'm testing on an actual device and in the emulator.

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml to allow the app to access fine locations? (i.e. `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`)

Comment: Yes, I also have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Marek Finnaly I implemented my own phonegap plugin using google play services that handle this problem better.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the problem was actually different, I had to enable high accuracy *and* raise the timeout interval.